# Exporting environment variables to Makefile shell

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to do immediate expansion of a shell command within a Makefile, but I want the shell command to have access to the environment variables within the Makefile.  If I use the $(shell ...), it expands immediately, but there is no access to the variables.  If I use the backquotes, the expansion is not immediate, and it causes problems for me later in the Makefile.  I'm wondering if there is any way to make the backquotes expand immediately, or to pass the current environment to a $(shell) command.

For example, the following makefile:

```
SOME_VAR := some_val
export SOME_VAR

VAR1 := `echo $$SOME_VAR`
export VAR1
VAR2 := `echo $$VAR1`

all:
      @echo VAR1=$(VAR1)
      @echo VAR2=$(VAR2)
```

Will output:

```
~/tmp/t2> make
VAR1=some_val
VAR2=`echo $SOME_VAR`
```

Where I want it to print "VAR2=some_val".  The real example is a bit more complicated (environment variables are inherited from parent makefiles, and I'm trying to use a perl script to edit the variables), but the principle is the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in some of the comments, my actual goal was to make the script generate filenames based on the settings the object was being compiled with.  I then need another script to generate a specially formatted list of all the filenames generated (the target is an embedded system which doesn't have a JIT compiler on it).  At any given time, there are over thirty settings which can potentially effect the binary, and this may be used on more than one module in the future, so I'd like something scalable.

My solution is as follows.  Instead of passing the variables in, I modified my script to output a makefile-parsable string based on the settings:

```
-include $(SOME_MK_FILE)

$(SOME_MK_FILE) : .phony
    script.pl $(SETTINGS_OF_INTEREST_LIST) > $(SOME_MK_FILE)

someFilename := $(shell script2.pl $(VAR1))
```

script.pl outputs a string that looks something like:

```
VAR1 := CONFIG_X1=$(CONFIG_X1) CONFIG_X2=$(CONFIG_X2) CONFIG_X33=$(CONFIG_X33)
```

and script2 outputs a filename that looks something like 'someFilename.X1_y.X2_n.elf'

and then, later on, in another rule, I have:

```
someobj: somedep
    script3.pl $(someFilename) >> builtfiles.txt
```

which properly builds builtfiles.txt (which in turn is the input for yet another script...).  In the end this is a workaround to the fact that make cannot pass its environement to $(shell).  It's not overly pretty but it works.

John

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

`VAR2 := $(shell VAR1="$(VAR1)" script_that_uses_var1)`

Comment: Not exactly, no.  What I want is to build certain binaries, and name them according to the current configuration.  While I could explicitly export each of the settings I want, this solution is not very scalable.  So, what I need to do is run a script which has access to all of the makefile settings.  It would then be able to output a filename.  The filename that would eventually need to be passed into another script later on, so the filename would have to resolve sooner rather than later.

Comment: This may not have helped the OP but it was exactly what I needed searching for this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with this?

```
VAR1 := $(shell echo $(SOME_VAR))
VAR2 := $(shell echo $(VAR1))
```

Comment: Hmmm... yes, my example was flawed... In the above example, VAR1 is expanded within the Makefile, but what I need is VAR1 to be expanded within the shell script.  That is, I'm calling a perl script which needs to access ENV{'VAR1'}.  If invoked from $(shell...) the script will have no knowledge of what VAR1 is.  I'll edit my question with a better example.  Thanks.

Comment: @John, I really can't understand what you're trying to do here. I could make a few guesses, but I think it would be faster if you edited your question.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do:  I have a makefile which is supposed to build an object file and name it according to the configuration settings it was built with.  I have a perl script which translates configuration settings into a name.  In order for this to work, the perl script has to have access to the configuration settings (have to use backquotes for that).  This would be fine by itself, but then the name has to be used in another perl script.  Because the name is not expanded by the time the second script is run, it causes an error.  I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: @John, why not have one script call the other?

Comment: Unfortunately that would complicate my Makefile worse than my existing solution.  I have a workaround, though it's not pretty -- the original script is called with $(shell), so it does not have access into the environment variables.  Instead, it outputs an assignment instruction using $(CONFIG_XXX) references into a new file.  The original makefile then does a -include of the new file.  It's hackish, but I've tested it and it works.  It would have been nice to do this in a cleaner manner, but I don't think one exists.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [Special Built-in Target Name](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eEXPORT_005fALL_005fVARIABLES): `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`

```
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:

MY_VAR = foo

test:
  @echo $$MY_VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

export FOO=bar

Here's a page with a lot more info:
http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/basics-getting-environment-variables-gnu-make?page=0%2C1

Comment: doesn't work for me. in shell this var doesn't exist