# Pass bash shell variable to Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, cp

Inside my **env.sh**:

```
export BIN="/home/user/stuff"
```

Inside my **Makefile**:

blah blah

```
TARGET = filetobeinstalled
```

blah blah

```
install:
       cp $(TARGET) $(BIN)
```

Prior to running `make install`, I define my env vars within my bash shell like this: `source /home/user/env.sh`. I double check that these env vars are working by typing `echo $BIN` in the shell that I'm running the Makefile, which gives me the appropriate response (`/home/user/stuff`).

So, I'm trying to pass the `$BIN` variable defined at the shell prompt with `source`, to inside of my **Makefile**, which references `$BIN`, but does not define it. Unfortunately, when I run `make install`, it does not pick up `$BIN` as you can see from the output

```
$ source /home/user/env.sh
$ echo $BIN
$ /home/user/stuff
$ make install

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/stufftoinstall'
cp filetobeinstalled
cp: missing destination file operand after `filetobeinstalled'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
```

On the line that has `cp filetobeinstalled`, I would expect it to pick up my env vars set using `source` prior to running `make install` so that line should read `cp filetobeinstalled /home/user/stuff` instead, but it doesn't.

I've found similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606079/exporting-environment-variables-to-makefile-shell) and bits and pieces scattered around the interwebs, but nothing definitive for the above problem and/or nothing that has worked so far. Hopefully this isn't too obvious, but go easy on me as I'm definitely a Makefile-nubile.

Cheers

Comment: Normally, `make` interprets environment variables as default values for `make` variables of the same name.  There's an option `-e` to change the priority of environment variables. Check what you get when you type `env | grep '^BIN='`.  If that doesn't show anything, that's why `make` is complaining.  If it does show the correct value for the `BIN` environment variable, I'm not sure what's up.  We might need to see the special rules at the top of the `makefile`.

Comment: How does `env.sh` get sourced in your shell? It's not a standard configuration file, and Make uses `sh`, not `bash`, by default, so it's possible that `env.sh` is not used by your Makefile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - yep, it spits out `BIN=/home/user/stuff`. Which parts of the Makefile would help?

Comment: @chepner - I just run a `source ~/whereis/env.sh` at the shell before running make. It's not embedded within a script or the Makefile. Yeah, good point and I did come across this issue [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_5.html#SEC46), but adding `SHELL := /bin/bash` to my Makefile didn't help.

Comment: Is there a macro `BIN =` (with no value) in the `makefile`?  Or with a value? If so, that takes priority over the environment, unless you use the `-e` option I mentioned before.

Comment: try `export BIN="/home/user/stuff/"` in your env.sh

Comment: You can test how `$(BIN)` got its (empty) value by adding a command `@echo $(origin BIN)` to the `install` rule, at least GNU make can do this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I didn't define BIN inside of the makefile, as I was trying to use the $BIN defined at the bash shell (i.e., by running `source ~/env.sh` prior to running make. If I hardcode something in the makefile, it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: @user2719058 - `cp $(TARGET) @echo $(origin BIN)` gave me `cp filetobeinstalled @echo undefined`. Not sure I did that right, but let me know.

Comment: @jayeshbhoi - oops - didn't see the extra '/' you added there. Nope, didn't work.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `make -f <(echo $'%:\n\t@echo $(origin BIN)') :`? Again `undefined`?

Comment: @user2719058 - I get `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`. Prior to running, `echo $BIN` gives me the correct path.

Comment: @Prophet60091: Sounds like you omitted the terminating colon in my command.

Comment: @user2719058 - `make -f <(echo $'%:\n\t@echo $(origin BIN)') :` reported `environment`

Comment: @Prophet60091 Ok, `$(BIN)` is defined in my little de-facto-Makefile, inherited from the environment like it's supposed to be. There must be something wrong in the Makefile(s) you are using.

Comment: @user2719058 - uh, I feel pretty stupid. You're right: one of the Makefiles that gets referenced actually refers to `$(BINDIR)` and not `$(BIN)`. Sloppy coding on the part of the author, but it seems to be the culprit here. Not sure what I should do for an answer. Can I spread it amongst all the folks here who helped point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to export variables you define in the env file, only environment variables are passed to a child process, not shell local ones. And I would make the name longer (like in the below example) to avoid possible clashes with anything else.

```
export BINDIR=/bin/path ;# will do
BINDIR=/bin/path; export BINDIR ;# will do as well
BINDIR=/bin/path make install ;# even this willd
make BINDIR=/bin/path install ;# and this, though using a different mechanism
```

Addition:

If you add the below target then you can run `make var=whatever printvar` and it will print the value of the variable `whatever`. It may help debugging it.

```
.PHONY: printvar
printvar:
    @echo "[$(var)]=[$($(var))]"
```

In addition, if you run `make` with `-np` it will run in a dry run mode and will print all defined variables, so you can do `make -np install | fgrep -w BIN` and see what you have.

Comment: I need a little more unpacking/clarification. Is the above supposed to be defined in my env.sh file? The export var in question is definitely in my env.sh file, and prior to running `make install`, running an `echo $BIN` at the shell gets me the correct path.

Comment: I updated the answer with suggestion on debugging the problem

Comment: I found `make -np install` insightful, so kudos for that. It shows `BIN = /home/user/stuff`, but obviously that's not working. Interestingly, it shows my makefile shell set to `SHELL = bin/sh` even though I've set it to `SHELL = bin/bash` in the Makefile as per @chepner's suggestion.